# Find an equivalent formula for the sum = 2+4+6+.....+2n?

Tags: sequences-and-series

we know that $1+2+3+4+5.....+n=n(n+1)/2$

I spent a lot of time trying to get a formula for this sum but I could not get it :

$( 2 + 3 + . . . + 2n)$

I tried to write the sum of some few terms.. Of course I saw some pattern between the sums but still the formula I Got didn't give a correct sum for other terms.

Is there another way of solving this question?

Comment: 2(1+2+3+4+5+...)

Comment: I can't help but laugh that someone downvoted this without leaving any comment indicating what the OP can improve about the question.  To the downvoter: in what way does such a downvote contribute to the site?  Here, I'll answer it for you: **it doesn't in any way**.

Comment: Do you mean $1+2+3+\cdots+2n$ (as in the text of the question) or $2+4+6+\cdots+2n$ (as in the title)?

Comment: Thanks, I just corrected that

Comment: You can also do a Gauss-style thing on it: $(2+2n)+(4+(2n-2))+\dotsb$

Comment: @Maher: It still isn't fixed. You now just have a *different* sum that disagrees with that in your title.

Comment: @user46944 Downvotes help to indicate to those browsing the site whether a question is worth reading (notice that the hover text includes "it is unclear or **not useful**"), for one. I'd say that's a contribution.

Comment: @epimorphic Did you read my entire original comment?  At the end of the day, this site is about *content*.  This site is run almost entirely by its users, so it's up to each of us to use the voting system responsibly.  This entails not only voting when we see that something is done right or wrong, but informing the creator of the content on how we think they can *improve* the content.  The downvoter didn't tell OP anything about what they thought was wrong with the question -- how the heck can the content be **improved** without this necessary information?

Comment: @epimorphic I want to end my last comment with saying: voting for the sake of voting is a practice done a lot on this site (and it's a really bad habit).  Lots of people don't take the added step of trying to help improve the content.  So basically, they are doing only half of the work.  I would not want to drive a car that is half assembled, or eat chicken that is only half cooked, etc.  If you aren't up to doing the full job, then why volunteer to work at all?

Comment: @user46944 I did. But notice that you bolded "it doesn't [contribute] in any way" in your original comment, which seems to suggest that you wanted to emphasize that part in particular. My comment was a reaction to that, as well as your tone ("I can't help but laugh that...").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$2+4+6+\cdots+2n = 2\left(1+2+3+\cdots+n\right) = 2 \cdot \dfrac{n(n+1)}2 = n(n+1)$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: can you see a factor $2$ somewhere ...

Answer (score 2):

different sums are in the title and body
title sum is
$$ 2+4+\ldots+2n = 2\left(1+\ldots+n\right)$$
which is easy since you yourself said what that sum is.

body sum us 
$$1+2+...+2n = 1+2+...+M$$
with $M=2n$ and now plug back into the same formula